# Вызов функции по указателю из метода шаблонного класса?

Tags: c++, указатели, шаблоны-с++

Ожидался вывод "11" по завершению программы, однако несмотря на то что компилятор скушал код без вопроса, программа прерывается ошибкой.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
template <class ptrType> class A
{
public:
    ptrType ptrData;
    A<ptrType>::A(ptrType S)
   {
       ptrType ptrData = S;
       ptrData();//Вызов Foo по указателю из конструктора класса.(работает)
   }
void Foo2();
};
template <class ptrType>void A<ptrType>::Foo2()
{
    ptrData();//Вызов Foo по указателю.(не работает)
}
    void Foo()//Интересующий функция.
{
    cout << "1";
};
int main()
{
    typedef void(*PTR_Foo)();
    PTR_Foo ptrFoo = &(Foo);//Указатель на функцию Foo
    A<PTR_Foo>  a(ptrFoo);
    a.Foo2();//Вызов Foo2 из экземпляра а класса А 
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: А ошибку мы должны угадать, чтобы было интереснее?

Comment: Я думал она и так понятна. Вызвано исключение по адресу 0x00000000 в ConsoleApplication3.exe: 0xC0000005: нарушение прав доступа при исполнении по адресу 0x00000000.

Comment: ну как бы это NPE.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Проблема в строчке

```
ptrType ptrData = S;
```

Вы присваиваете `S` локальной переменной, а не полю с тем же именем.

Пишите просто

```
ptrData = S;
```

Или даже лучше так:

```
A<ptrType>::A(ptrType S) : ptrData(S)
{
    ptrData();
}
```

---

Обновление (из дискуссии в комментариях):

Для вызова функции-члена вместо свободной функции `Foo` можно использовать указатель на функцию-член:

```
void (A<PTR_Foo>::*f)() = &A<PTR_Foo>::Foo2;
(a.*f)();
```

При этом для вызова нужен экземпляр объекта типа `A`.

Вы можете также превратить указатель на функцию-член в функтор (что-то типа свободной функции) при помощи `std::function`. Для нового класса `B`:

```
class B
{
public:
    void Foo() { cout << "1"; };
};
```

получаем:

```
B b;
std::function<void()> f2 = std::bind(&B::Foo, b);
f2();
```

— и вы можете передавать `f2` в другой класс. При этом, понятно, вы обязаны гарантировать, что объект `b`, к которому привязан теперь функтор `f2`, будет жить в момент вызова.

Ну или вы можете завести умный указатель на него, чтобы не заботиться о времени жизни:

```
std::shared_ptr<B> pb = std::make_shared<B>();
std::function<void()> f2 = std::bind(&B::Foo, pb);
f2();
```

---

P.S.: По-моему, C++ — избыточно сложный язык.

Comment: Спасибо! :) в голове за день вакуум какой-то, мог и сам понять :С

Comment: @Krychun Ivan: Пожалуйста :)

Comment: а как быть если функция `Foo()` является членом другого класса? странную ошибку дает мол после вычисления фрагмента не является функция, принимающая 0 аргументов.

Comment: @KrychunIvan: Так с функцией-членом не получится, т. к. она не приводится к указателю на функцию (да это и понятно, к ней нужен её `this` для вызова). Тут нужен другой синтаксис: `void (A<PTR_Foo>::*f)() = &A<PTR_Foo>::Foo2; (a.*f)();`. (Я не виноват, что в C++ такой странный синтаксис.)

Comment: я имею введу: `class B{public:void Foo(){ cout << "1";};`, разумеется и объявление типа изменится `typedef void(B::*PTR_Foo)();` как и инициализация указателя `PTR_Foo ptrFoo = &(B::Foo);`, но при попытке компиляции мы получаем ошибку об аргументе. Или я вас не до конца понял, или вы меня  =\

Comment: @KrychunIvan: Прекрасно работает: `void (B::*f1)() = &B::Foo; (b.*f1)();`. Само собой разумеется, для вызова функции-члена вам нужен объект `b` типа `B`.

Comment: это разумеется работать будет, хотелось бы получить вот такую цепочку: создается экземпляр шаблонного класса `А` метод `Foo2()` , которого вызывает метод `Foo1()` класса `B`, скорее всего мне не хватает указателя на объект класса `B`, что бы оно заработало. И наверное необходимо его предавать конструктору шаблонного класса `A`.

Comment: @KrychunIvan: Если вы хотите отвязаться от объекта `b`, попробуйте так: `std::function<void()> f2 = std::bind(&B::Foo, b); f2();`. И передавайте `f2`. Или вы можете «запихнуть» в `std::function` лямбду. Позаботьтесь о том, чтобы объект `b` не умер раньше времени. (Ну или заведите на него `shared_ptr`.) Вам уже говорили, что C++ — избыточно сложный язык?

Answer (score 1):

В конструкторе класса `A` вы не инициализируете член класса `ptrData`: вместо этого вы вводите новую локальную переменную, которая скрывает поле. Соответственно при вызове функции `Foo2` и происходит обращение к некорректному участку памяти